# confusing results for ansi code to query cursor position (\033[6n)

Tags: bash

When I try to get the column and position of the cursor in a bash shell, the value returned does not match what I would think it to be.

For example when I have a prompt that looks like so:

`user@machine: echo -en '\033[6n`

I would expect the column to be the value of the column where the cursor was when I hit enter (in this case 32 as I'm counting what PS1 renders). However, the reported column is always 1. Confusingly, the row number is always correct.

If I then change the command to:

`echo -en 'xxx\033[6n'`

I then get an answer of 4.

I think I have conceptual misunderstanding of what the escape code is actually querying. What is the misunderstanding on my part? If I wanted to get the position of the cursor when I hit enter, how would I go about it?

Comment: How are you capturing the input that's triggered by the escape sequence?

Comment: If you have that in your prompt, it will get the cursor position after `user@machine:` is printed, not where the cursor was before the prompt was printed.

Comment: How do you expect putting `echo -en` in the prompt will cause anything to be executed? The prompt isn't executed as a command, it's just a text string.

Comment: I think what's going on here is this: you enter the command followed by `enter`. bash echos back the `enter`, thus positioning the cursor to the left column, and executes the command. Thus you always see column 1. Similarly for your second version, but now the first few characters change the cursor position you read.

Comment: Could you show what you've actually put in `PS1`? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Now I understand. This isn't the contents of your prompt, it's what you typed at the prompt. I thought you were trying to get your prompt to display the cursor position dynamically.

Comment: It's worth remembering that this is a _terminal_ feature, not a bash feature. It's not something bash knows about or does anything special for; terminal control sequences work exactly the same when triggered by `echo -e` as they would if triggered by strings written from Python; so if there's something bash would need to do differently to "stay out of the way" of that feature, that's... not something it's going to do.

Comment: Also, note that this is asynchronous. There is a bash process. And a terminal (historically a physical one, to and from which you send and receive messages through a serial lines. Now, unless — as I confess I am a bit — you are some kind of retro-geek, with a physical ADM-5 terminal connected to a raspberry, that terminal is software. Nevertheless, that is transparent. Everything is as if there was and external device, to which you send messages with `echo` (or anything that writes to stdout), and from which you receive things with `read` (or anythng that reads from stdin).

Comment: So, that `echo ^[6n` → read cursor pos, should not be seen as query command from bash. It is an exchange of messages. Asynchronous one. Exactly as if you were echoing "where do you see the cursor" to a user, and expecting that user to type on the physical keyboard "to that position" sometimes, later.

Comment: Reason why `echo ^[6n ; read x` doesn't read the cursor position in `x`. and wouldn't necessarily do so even if the "echo command" were interpreted before you hit enter (which, anyway, it is not). Nothings says when exactly the teriminal will "type" the answer to the `^[6n` "question". In other words, it is not very reliable to mix up user input (as in a prompt) and "virtual" input. It is exactly as if 2 users were having each their keyboard, and typing together. Hard to be 100% sure which input you are reading (if not interleaved ones). Sure, mixup is less likely when one

Comment: of the users is a slow human. with typing timings in dozens of ms, and the other is a robot (the terminal, external device, or process), that, even tho it should not be considered synchronous, has reaction times in μs. Yet, as unlikely it is, it is not impossible, and that would not be a good design to rely on luck, even probable one. Especially for something that would occur (if you use your teriminal as often as I do) hundred of times every day for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the misunderstanding on my part?

You type `echo -en '\033[6n'`.

The press enter.

Cursor goes to the next line.

Then bash executes the command `echo -en '\033[6n`.

Then TTY outputs the cursor location. Cursor is on the next line on column 1. So the column will be 1.

I believe what is misunderstood is the expectancy that the command is executed before shifting lines up and setting cursor location to the next line. The command is executed after shifting the cursor position to the next line.

> If I wanted to get the position of the cursor when I hit enter, how would I go about it?

In any case, you would not use an interactive shell. You would write and run your own program that queries the cursor location without the requirement of pressing enter and has proper logic to parse escape sequences returned by TTY.

Comment: Makes complete sense to me! Thanks!